# Post excerpt showing urls after upgrade to 5.30

Tags: ghost-blog

I just updated from Ghost 4.x to Ghost 5.x and all of a sudden I'm getting things like this from {{excerpt}}:

> Originally published by Mobi Health News [https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news/upstream-raises-140m-scale-value-based-primary-care-support-services?mkt_tok=NDIwLVlOQS0yOTIAAAGIbq3LRAT3TSVIDdGo-yqCugCQAulToWn6iRcGu1VAMKVtx0Ml7RGTwZWfKPkvV0MK_lVsF4GqIIdTRRfpnVP7z4zFUr4mNT4MVImJKqkI] on December 1, 2022…

Before it was stripping out the url like so

> Originally published by Mobi Health News on December 1, 2022. Upstream Healthcare, which offers technology and support services for...

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Until Ghost updates their docs with a more elegant solution, you can remove the items manually with Javascript using Regex

```
let newExcerpt = item.node.excerpt.replace(/ *\[[^)]*\] */g, " ")
```

This will replace anything within [] parenthesis in your string. For example

```
"This link [https://google.com] works"
```

Would become

```
"This link works"
```